# Ошибка в рекурсивной функции

Tags: рекурсия, php

Есть функция генерации случайного набора символов.

Решил переделать ее с рекурсией.

Генерируем код, проверяем, если ли такой код в базе, если есть - повторно запускаем функцию, итерацию сделал - но периодически получаю в результате пустую строку, либо все-таки, несмотря на проверку, возвращается значение, которое уже есть в базе.

```
function generate_url($longurl,$j) {

    //global $email;
    $keys = "23456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $i    = 0;
    $url  = "";

    while ($i < $longurl) {
      $random = mt_rand(0, strlen($keys) - 1);
      $url   .= $keys{$random};
      $i++;
    }
$j--;
$gen=mysql_query("SELECT short FROM url WHERE short= '$url'");
        $gen_check=mysql_num_rows($gen);

    if ($gen_check>0)
        {

            //echo $j;
        if ($j>0)
            {
                echo $j;
                generate_url($longurl,$j);
            }
        else
            {
                mail($email,$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].' - url warning','generated url was found in database! do something!');
                die('error! please contact server admin!'); 
            }
        }
    else
        {
            return $url;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

А не проще ли сделать циклом?

Answer (score 0):

Тут

```
if ($j>0)
    {
        echo $j;
        generate_url($longurl,$j);
    }
```

Должно быть что-то типа

```
    if ($j>0)
        {
            echo $j;
            return generate_url($longurl,$j);
        }
```

Я бы переписал так, без всяких "смертей":

```
    $keys = "23456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        function generate_url($longurl, $keys) {
            $i = 0;
            $url  = "";
            while ($i < $longurl) {
              $random = mt_rand(0, strlen($keys) - 1);
              $url   .= $keys{$random};
              $i++;
            }
            $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM url WHERE short= '".$url."'";
            $gen = mysql_query($sql);
            if($gen === false) return false;
            $gen_check = mysql_result($gen, 0);
            if($gen_check > 0) return generate_url($longurl, $keys);
            return $url;
        }
```

**UPDATE**
После долгих размышлений получил вариант доказательства "теоремы о бесконечных обезьянах" в вариации "зачем нам теория перестановок - рандомом нагенерируем все возможные уникальные значения". Ну а с другой стороны, при наличии 40 тысяч комбинаций функция генерирует новую примерно за 0,04 секунды - так что почему бы и нет?

Результат:

```
function generateUrl($length, $keys, $url = '', $level = 0) {
    $keys_temp = $keys;
    while(strlen($keys_temp) != 0) {
        $rand = mt_rand(0, strlen($keys_temp) - 1);
        $temp_liter = $keys_temp{$rand};
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM url WHERE short LIKE '".$url.$temp_liter."%' AND LENGTH(short) = '".$length."'";
        $unical = mysql_query($sql);
        $unical = mysql_result($unical, 0);
        if($unical < pow( strlen($keys), ($length - ($level +1)) )) {
            $url .= $temp_liter;
            $level ++;
            if($level == $length) return $url;
            return generateUrl($length, $keys, $url, $level);
        }
        else {
            $keys_temp = str_replace($temp_liter, '', $keys_temp); 
        }
    }
return false;
}
```

Применение:

```
$keys = "23456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; //Минут 10 не мог баг найти, причина которого была в двух "G"... )
$url = generateUrl(7, $keys);
```

Ну и небольшое уточнение: 
поле "short" должно быть "BINARY", иначе будет идти регистронезависимый поиск.

Comment: неа, еще есть варианты, а я получаю
''die('error! please contact server admin!'); ''

Comment: В этом случае $j меньше нуля. И зачем вообще рекурсию ограничивать? А без "return" нет рекурсии - результат возвращается только как однократное выполнение функции, остальные вызовы - бесполезная задержка. 

Кроме того, рекурсия неоправданна - цикл для решения задачи подходит лучше.

Добавил в ответ свой пример решения задачи. отправку мыла, если так нужна, следует выполнять, если функция вернет false.

Comment: уже лучше, но когда заканчиваются варианты - скрипт зависает. вот вам и без смертей :)

Comment: Поэтому рекурсия и не оправдана...)

Comment: очень даже оправдана.. мне нужно максимальное количество раз проверять базу при каждой новой генерации кода (короткой ссылки), так как, если случайно сгенерился код, который уже есть в базе, мы просто генерируем новый и проверяем опять. плодить 10-20-30-50 циклов - ЭТО не оправдано

Comment: Откуда там 10 циклов? О_о Всего один - 

do {/* Проверка на уникальность */}while($gen_check > 0);

Кроме того, mt_rand() вполне может выдать подряд несколько одинаковых последовательностей, что, разумеется, скажется неблагоприятно на производительность. Если уточните задачу - возможно, смогу подсказать решение. Сейчас мне кажется, что алгоритм не доработан.

Кстати, не помешает исходный (нерекурсивный) вариант функции "генерации случайного набора символов", которая решает (?) поставленную задачу.

Comment: function generate_url($longurl) {
    $keys = "23456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $i    = 0;
    $url  = "";

    while ($i < $longurl) {
      $random = mt_rand(0, strlen($keys) - 1);
      $url   .= $keys{$random};
      $i++;
    }

    return $url;
}

Comment: Нужно, чтобы значение выдавалось уникальное, и более того, конкретной длинны? Хитрая задача... На ум приходит только одно решение пошаговой генерации, т.е. проверка будет производится после каждого добавления в строку символа из набора... И рекурсия будет оправдана... Сейчас попробую замутить...

Answer (score 0):

[@Ozim](/users/2690/ozim), если я правильно понимаю задачу, то вам не то чтобы рекурсия - вам генерация коротких ссылок сама по себе не нужна. Используйте last_insert_id() в качестве url, можно его в hex кодировать для укорочения - вот и все дела, и никаких лишних проверок...

Comment: Если речь идет именно об URL, то такой вариант вряд ли будет решением, ибо то, что id записи будет уникален не гарантирует того, что url в виде этого id еще не использовался. При таком подходе лучше оставлять поле 'url' пустым, а урл выводить в неком формате "sitename/ЗарезервированноеСлово/ID".

Comment: Не использовался кем и где? Про использование мы ничего не знаем, да и вообще, про задачу - это только предположение...

Comment: нет, это не подходит.